# Video Trimming In Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Am developing an app which a user can upload a video status just like whatsapp but I need a video trimming library which I can use to implement this feature where a user can trim some portion of the video they selected with a time frame. I searched and found some libraries like react-native-video-processing and others but none seems to work with expo. so I will appreciate if someone can give me a working one or a guide on how I can use ffmpeg or other libraries to archive this.